# Array value fetching in asm x64

Tags: arrays, assembly, 64-bit, x86-64

I have a problem with asm code that works when mixed with C, but does not when used in asm code with proper parameters.

```
;; array - RDI, x- RSI, y- RDX
getValue:   
   mov r13, rsi
   sal r13, $3
   mov r14, rdx
   sal r14, $2
   mov r15, [rdi+r13]
   mov rax, [r15+r14]

   ret
```

Technically I want to keep the rdi, rsi and rdx registers untouched and thus I use other ones.

I am using an x64 machine and thus my pointers have 8 bytes. Technically speaking this code is supposed to do:

```
int getValue(int** array, int x, int y) {
    return array[x][y];
}
```

it somehow works inside my C code, but does not when used in asm in this way:

```
mov rdi, [rdi]    ;; get first pointer - first row
mov r9,  $4       ;; we want second element from the row
mov rax, [rdi+r9] ;; get the element (4 bytes vs 8 bytes???)
mov rdi, FMT      ;; prepare printf format "%d", 10, 0
mov rsi, rax      ;; we want to print the element we just fetched
mov eax, $0       ;; say we have no non-integer argument
call printf       ;; always gives 0, no matter what's in the matrix
```

Can someone see into this and help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sal r14, $2` implies the elements are dwords, so the last line before the `ret` shouldn't load a qword. Besides, x86 has nice scaling addressing modes, so you can do this:

```
mov rax, [rdi + rsi * 8]  ; load pointer to column
mov eax, [rax + rdx * 4]  ; note this loads a dword
ret
```

That implies that you have an array of pointers to *columns*, which is unusual. You can do that, but was it intended?

Comment: OK, but how can I print it now? Asking, because I'm just starting with ASM and x64 and I know no method to convert a 32-bit value to 64-bit value (printf takes standard 8-byte registers as first parameters, so "mov rsi, eax" will not work).

Comment: You can use `movsxd rsi, eax` to sign-extend it to 64 bits. If it's unsigned or known to be positive, you can just `mov esi, eax` it.

Comment: Thanks. This worked really great. I have tested it before, but I was stupid to change eax to 0 before assigning calculated value to rsi... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard matrix of integers.

```
int** array;
sizeof(int*) == 8
sizeof(int) == 4
```

How I see it is that when I have that array at first, I have a pointer to a space of memory without "blanks" that holds all pointers one by one (index-by-index), so I say "let's go to the element rsi-th of the array" and that's why I shift by rsi-th * 8 bytes. So now I get the same situation, but the pointer should point to a space of integers, so 4-byte items. That's why I shift by 4 bytes there.

Is my thinking wrong?